# MS Word document gone cut paste error

Tags: microsoft-word

One of my colleagues has experienced a strange occurence using cut and paste.

A MS Word file was cut out with CTRL + X and a new folder was selected to paste it with CTRL + V. The file was no longer saved for some reason and couldn't be pasted. It was not in the old folder either and also not in the trash can.

Is this file lost forever? Could the clipboard be erased automatically? There were only a few seconds in between and we only have daily backups. Could be rather expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would not have deleted the file. It is almost certain that it got moved to some location that was the focus of the mouse, while not realizing it. The key is to finding it.

I would do a search of both the local drives, and the network drives. You will need to know the name of the file, or try a search sorted by date at a command prompt:

```
dir "name of file*.doc" /s

dir *.* /s /t:w /o:-d /p
```

Answer (score 1):

Where the file could be, I cannot say. But the file content is normally not in the clipboard.

If you move a file via copy and paste, a link to the file gets put into the clipboard with additional information if it was copied (Ctrl-C) or cut (Ctrl-X).

On pasting (Ctrl-V), the file is copied or moved to the target depending on the said tag.

Is the containing source folder on a network? Maybe someone took it out before

Comment: Yes it is on a network. Could be that someone deleted it but the admin will try if he can salvage it.